# Running mocha test in subfolders

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mocha.js

I am using Sails.js for some project. Now I wrote some unit tests. My test folder hierarchy is like following:

```
/test
    bootstrat.test.js
    mocha.opts
    /unit
        /controller
            User.js
            Representative.js
        /model
            User.js
            Representative.js
        /service
            Utility.js
```

For testing I now have to run all these following commands:

```
$ mocha test/unit/controller
$ mocha test/unit/model
$ mocha test/unit/service
```

But this is time consuming and too manual. I wanted to run all these tests with just one command and searched Google. I tried running `mocha --recursive test`. But it's not working. It results in following error -

```
  1) "before all" hook
  2) "after all" hook

  0 passing (2s)
  2 failing

  1)  "before all" hook:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
      at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:159:19)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)

  2)  "after all" hook:
     TypeError: Cannot call method 'lower' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (/home/gladiator/Codes/rms-generic-web/test/bootstrap.test.js:21:9)
      at Hook.Runnable.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:218:15)
      at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:259:10)
      at Object._onImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:276:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:345:15)
```

Is there a way in which I can run all these tests with just one command?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to make you own bash script ?

Create mocha.sh and put this in it :

```
#!/bin/bash

mocha test/unit/controller
mocha test/unit/model
mocha test/unit/service
```

And run it with `sh ./mocha.sh`

I don't know enough mocha to do it with it.

Comment: But it's too platform dependent. What if some developer works in Unix and some in Windows.

Comment: Yes you are right, you can create a bash also for windows and let developer use the correct one but I think there a better way, mocha or node supporte this for sure but I don't know how. Maybe someone you give you the answer

Answer (score 1):

In your **package.json** file just add the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha ./test -b -t 10000"
 }
```

-b stops your tests after the first failure.

-t is test-case timeout in milliseconds

Then from the directory containing the package.json and test folder run `npm test` command. It will run all your tests.

Comment: `0 passing (2 ms)`. But there are test cases. I think it is not working recursively.